# Suggestions for Querying Database for Names

Tags: sql, oracle, full-text-search, soundex, oracle-text

I have an Oracle database that, like many, has a table containing biographical information. On which, I would like to search by name in a "natural" way.

The table has `forename` and `surname` fields and, currently, I am using something like this:

```
select id, forename, surname
from   mytable
where  upper(forename) like '%JOHN%'
and    upper(surname) like '%SMITH%';
```

This works, but it can be very slow because the indices on this table obviously can't account for the preceding wildcard. Also, users will usually be searching for people based on what they tell them over the phone -- including a huge number of non-English names -- so it would be nice to also do some phonetic analysis.

As such, I have been experimenting with Oracle Text:

```
create index forenameFTX on mytable(forename) indextype is ctxsys.context;
create index surnameFTX on mytable(surname) indextype is ctxsys.context;

select   score(1)+score(2) relevance,
         id,
         forename,
         surname
from     mytable
where    contains(forename,'!%john%',1) > 0
and      contains(surname,'!%smith%',2) > 0
order by relevance desc;
```

This has the advantage of using the Soundex algorithm as well as full text indices, so it *should* be a little more efficient. (Although, my anecdotal results show it to be pretty slow!) The only apprehensions I have about this are:

- Firstly, the text indices need to be refreshed in some meaningful way. Using `on commit` would be too slow and might interfere with how the frontend software -- which is out of my control -- interacts with the database; so requires some thinking about...
- The results that are returned by Oracle aren't exactly very naturally sorted; I'm not really sure about this `score` function. For example, my development data is showing "Jonathan Peter Jason Smith" at the top -- fine -- but also "Jane Margaret Simpson" at the same level as "John Terrance Smith"

I'm thinking that removing the preceding wildcard might improve performance without degrading the results as, in real life, you would never search for a chunk in the middle of a name. However, otherwise, I'm open to ideas... This scenario must have been implemented ad nauseam! Can anyone suggest a better approach to what I'm doing/considering now?

Thanks :)

Comment: you might also consider Lucene for a non-Oracle fuzzy search engine (and its free).  But depends on your env and needs (and skillset)

Comment: Not so much of answer but a suggestion. I was using MySQL and full-text search, to search for account details - based on first and last names. I also experienced irrelevant results based on score, until I created a new column, "full_name", that contained first and last names together (de-normalization), then searched that column instead - my results were more precise and quicker to return. I also used the Boolean mode, so it matched both names "john" and "smith". If I didn't use the Boolean mode, it returned results for "john" or "smith", which was wrong

Comment: Are you allowed to change the database schema?

Comment: @MartinG Yes, I was considering concatenating the fields. I don't know if I can do that without changing the schema (i.e., use both columns in the CONTAINS function)...

Comment: ...which, @X-Zero, I can't do with regard to table columns; but I don't see a problem with adding indices.

Comment: For manual implementation you might want to consider suffix sorting -- algoritms like Sadakane or Manver-Myers. They must be quite simple to accomplish.

Comment: @Xophmeister - well, there goes adding a 'Names' table that you can FK reference (and contains permanent soundexes...)

Comment: @X-Zero: I misunderstood what you meant by "change the database schema". I thought you meant alter, rather than create new objects... I can do that and, following your suggestion, have come up with the solution, below :) Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have come up with a solution which works pretty well, following the suggestions in the comments. Particularly, @X-Zero's suggestion of creating a table of Soundexes: In my case, I *can* create new tables, but altering the existing schema is not allowed!

So, my process is as follows:

- Create a new table with columns: `ID`, `token`, `sound` and `position`; with the primary key over (`ID`, `sound`,`position`) and an additional index over (`ID`,`sound`).
- Go through each person in the biographical table:

  - Concatenate their forename and surname.
  - Change the codepage to `us7ascii`, so accented characters are normalised. This is because the Soundex algorithm doesn't work with accented characters.
  - Convert all non-alphabetic characters into whitespace and consider this the boundary between tokens.
  - Tokenise this string and insert into the table the token (in lowercase), the Soundex of the token and the position the token comes in the original string; associate this with `ID`.

Like so:

```
declare
  nameString varchar2(82);
  token varchar2(40);
  posn integer;
  cursor myNames is
    select id,
           forename||' '||surname person_name
    from   mypeople;
begin
  for person in myNames
  loop
    nameString := trim(
                    utl_i18n.escape_reference(
                      regexp_replace(
                        regexp_replace(person.person_name,'[^[:alpha:]]',' '),
                        '\s+',' '),
                      'us7ascii')
                    )||' ';
    posn := 1;
    while nameString is not null
    loop
      token := substr(nameString,1,instr(nameString,' ') - 1);
      insert into personsearch values (person.id,lower(token),soundex(token),posn);
      nameString := substr(nameString,instr(nameString,' ') + 1);
      posn := posn + 1;
    end loop;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

So, for example, "Siân O'Conner" gets tokenised into "sian" (position 1), "o" (position 2) and "conner" (position 3) and those three entries, with their Soundex, get inserted into `personsearch` along with their ID.

- To search, we do the same process: tokenise the search criteria and then return results where the Soundexes and *relative* positions match. We order by the position and then the Levenshtein distance (`ld`) from the original search for each token, in turn.

This query, for example, will search against two tokens (i.e., pre-tokenised search string):

```
with     searchcriteria as (
         select 'john'  token1,
                'smith' token2
         from   dual)
select   alpha.id,
         mypeople.forename||' '||mypeople.surname
from     peoplesearch alpha
join     mypeople
on       mypeople.student_id = alpha.student_id
join     peoplesearch beta
on       beta.student_id = alpha.student_id
and      beta.position   > alpha.position
join     searchcriteria
on       1 = 1
where    alpha.sound = soundex(searchcriteria.token1)
and      beta.sound  = soundex(searchcriteria.token2)
order by alpha.position,
         ld(alpha.token,searchcriteria.token1),
         beta.position,
         ld(beta.token,searchcriteria.token2),
         alpha.student_id;
```

To search against an arbitrary number of tokens, we would need to use dynamic SQL: joining the search table as many times as there are tokens, where the `position` field in the joined table must be greater than the `position` of the previously joined table... I plan to write a function to do this -- as well as the search string tokenisation -- which will return a table of IDs. However, I just post this here so you get the idea :)

As I say, this works pretty well: It returns good results pretty quickly. Even searching for "John Smith", once cached by the server, runs in less than 0.2s; returning over 200 rows... I'm pretty pleased with it and will be looking to put it into production. The only issues are:

- The precalculation of tokens takes a while, but it's a one-off process, so not too much of a problem. A related problem however is that a trigger needs to be put on the `mypeople` table to insert/update/delete tokens into the search table whenever the corresponding operation is performed on `mypeople`. This may slow up the system; but as this should only happen during a few periods in a year, perhaps a better solution would be to rebuild the search table on a scheduled basis.
- No stemming is being done, so the Soundex algorithm only matches on full tokens. For example, a search for "chris" will not return any "christopher"s. A possible solution to this is to only store the Soundex of the stem of the token, but calculating the stem is not a simple problem! This will be a future upgrade, possibly using the hyphenation engine used by TeX...

Anyway, hope that helps :) Comments welcome!

---

**EDIT** My full solution (write up and implementation) is now [here](http://xoph.co/20111007/building-a-better-search-engine/), using Metaphone and the Damerau-Levenshtein Distance.

Comment: The Levenshtein distance implementation I used can be found at http://www.merriampark.com/ldplsql.htm

Comment: ...I might experiment with Metaphone, instead of Soundex, too.

Comment: You're on 10g, so you should check out the UTL_MATCH package.  Its EDIT_DISTANCE() function is an implementation of the Levenshtein algorithm.  http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e10577/u_match.htm